# Unable to Instantiate View Controller

Tags: ios, swift, authentication, storyboard

I have a function, whereby I check if the UserDefaults are set and if not a new View Controller opens and presents a login screen which will set the user defaults.

My problem is the view controller does not Instantiate but I get a print "User not registered"

```
func checkUserAccount() {
        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
        let accountName = defaults.bool(forKey: "PUserAccountName")
        let accountPassword = defaults.bool(forKey: "PUserAccountPassword")
        if accountName == true && accountPassword == true  {
            print("User Registered")

        } else {

            let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "PolTRiM", bundle: nil)
            let vc: StudentLoginVC  = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "studentLogin") as! StudentLoginVC
            vc.modalPresentationStyle = .custom
            vc.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve
            self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: { _ in })
            print("User not registered")
        }

    }
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: I have tried your code and its working, I think there is issue with the frames of views in StudentLoginVC so nothing is visible.

Comment: If app didn't crashed, it means `vc` is instantiated because you are force casting the instance. @laxmankhanal is correct.

Comment: @laxman, I did not find any specific errors, but decided to delete and rebuild the VC from scratch and using the code above it worked. So whilst there did not appear to be a problem, there must have been somewhere in the original VC or views.

Answer (score 1):

Have you double checked `UIStoryBoard` name and `UIViewController` identifier if it's written correctly? Otherwise this code is working for me

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier :"MyViewController") as! UIViewController
self.present(viewController, animated: true)
```

Comment: @bezoadam - yes all the spelling and syntax were correct.